# How can I type a symbol at the center of a square diagram in xymatrix?

Tags: labels, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

In order to speak about a particular square sitting inside a bigger diagram, I'm trying to add a symbol at its center, so that I can refer to it by using the symbol. The problem is that I don't know how to do that with xymatrix.. Is there a simple solution? I think that the following code can do the work, but it seems to me that there has to be a smarter way..

```
\xymatrix{
    A \ar[rr] \ar[dd] && B \ar[dd]\\
    & 1\\
    C \ar[rr] && D
}
```

Comment: just to confirm -- what you are looking for is a way to use the symbol in the middle of the square as the visible label, equivalent to the equation number on the entire diagram, so that you can use the `\ref` mechanism to refer to it.  is this so, or do you want something else?  i don't know of a way to embed such an element in an `xymatrix`.

Comment: No, that would be the best, but I don't think it is even possible. I'm looking for a smarter way to construct the exact same diagram that I wrote. The problem with my solution is that if you find out too late that you need a labeling similar to mine, you'd have to rewrite all the diagram from scratch. I hope there is a better solution that simply adds the symbol, without forcing you to change all the spacing and the arrows

Comment: the diagram your code produces looks reasonable.  why don't you just replace the "1" by a command name to which you can assign a value, use anywhere, and change the value if you need to do that later?  (i have a "canned" variant to this which produces a smaller square, which could be used in similar fashion.  but it doesn't answer your question directly.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I understand neither how to do what you are saying, nor how what you are saying can solve my problem.. I'm just looking for a sort of command that let me add a symbol in the center of a square diagram, so that if I have to label a particular square in a more complex construction, I can just write this command into the xymatrix code in order to add the "label"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this variant gives a smaller diagram than your example, but it's the same principle.

by using a command name instead of a hard-coded object, it's possible to refer to
the object later, or to change the object in only one place.

this may or may not satisfy your requirement, but it's too long to try to explain
in a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xypic}

\newcommand{\refsymbol}{{\ensuremath\theta}}

\begin{document}
Here we have a diagram.
\begin{equation}
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d]
  \ar@{}[dr] | {\refsymbol}
  & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}
\label{eq:diag}
\end{equation}
We want to refer to {\refsymbol} in the square shown in \eqref{eq:diag}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 2):

There is another option using a commutative diagram with `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-Stealth}]
A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr] &  & B \arrow[dd] \\
 & \alpha &  \\
C \arrow[rr] &  & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```